# how to check whether the id is existed or not in facebook which got from facebook api

Tags: javascript, java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I am doing a game which I need this. client will send the facebook id which got from facebook API, here I need to validate whether the client is sending the facebook id or sending some dummy id.

> Means If I got a id like "16759S43x5yXx31X" from the client like it is my facebook id, how to cross check the supplied id is facebook id or not.

Comment: Send the user access token to the server, and then make an API request for `/me` to get the user id from that.

Comment: Hi CBroe,
Thanks For The Response,
I am asking how to validate someone sent facebook id is existed in facebook or not, through my client programming I am getting id like /me query but I need to check the validity of some one send .for  authentication

Comment: So I could send any other profile’s id, and it would be “valid” – is that what you want?

Comment: yes need to check is it (others sent id) real fb id or not

Comment: And where does the user get this id from? // You can make an API request for the id, and see what response you get – although that might not be that reliable, because the API responses for stuff that doesn’t exist, and stuff the app is not allowed to “see” with the access token used, are often the same.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate whether "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture" is valid. This can be done with ajax from javascript i.e

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture",
    statusCode: {
        200: function() {
            alert("user exist");
        },
            404: function() {
            alert( "user not exist" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks david for the suggestion, My prog(server) doesn't have web interaction. and moreever I need a search of user with out login or an login script with out user interaction (like forms).
Rightnow I found a way by search userid/name in java using facebook4j,restfb but it needs login access tokens thats the problem for using those.